# Converting a static bootstrap navigation to wordpress navigation (more indepth)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have been learning how to use wordpress along with php and I am currently trying to convert a static website I have built using wordpress.

At the minute I am having trouble with the wordpress 'wp_nav_menu' being that I have a so-called split menu with the main navigation links on the left and some social media links on the right.

Here is my current markup:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Computer Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Accountancy Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Payroll Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social-icons">
      <li>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And how far I have gotten with the wordpress integration:

```
<?php
   wp_nav_menu( array (
      'theme_location'  => 'primary',
      'container'       => 'nav',
      'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
      'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
    ));
?>
```

Although I understand the social media links aren't exatly a menu I would like to know and understand how to have them still apart of the same container e.g.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Any help regarding the matter would be greatly appreciated and I am willing to learn from any mistakes as I am sure I have already made some (or bound to).

Comment: that's called a social menu on most of the themes build it apart from the main menu, so don't overcomplicate yourself trying to fit them all in just one menu

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I guess I just have to rework the layout a little.

It's a shame as I liked when the social media buttons/links were, it just tidied up the header a little bit, without it, it just looks a little empty.

Comment: either add the second menu or use something else to fill the social menu, like grabbing the links from some config or something else. the theme oxygen uses that second approach, maybe you could look into those files.

Comment: I will have a look, thank you for the headup much appreciated.